# D3.js style and class override not work as my expectation

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

May I know why my class "bold-header" styles didn't override to the first row`<tr>` of the table?

**HTML:**

```html
<style>
    .bold-header{
        background-color:navy;
        color:white;
    }
</style>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>001</td>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>002</td>
        <td>Alex</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>         
        <td>003</td>
        <td>Maxwell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```js
d3.select("table").selectAll("td").style("background-color", "lightblue").style("width", "100px");

d3.select("table").select("tr").classed("bold-header", true);
```

**I expect this result:**
[my expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADZhJ.jpg)

**but it gave me this:**
[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TDfN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background color is not working because we need to set background color on `<td>` element of first row. In your code, you are not selected corresponding `td's`.

The following changes are needed in second line of JS code:

```
d3.select("table").select("tr").selectAll("td").classed("bold-header", true);
```

**UPDATE**

I have understood the question and have updated the code, the another reason that your code is not working because you lightblue color is overriding the navy color. So, I would suggest you to select the header td tags and body td tags wisely. Please see the working code below

```js
d3.select("table").selectAll("tr:not(:first-child)").style("background-color", "lightblue").style("width", "100px");

d3.select("table").select("tr").classed("bold-header", true);
```

```css
 .bold-header{
        background-color:navy;
        color:white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>001</td>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>002</td>
        <td>Alex</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>         
        <td>003</td>
        <td>Maxwell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Assign class to `select("tr")` is same as `select("tr").selectAll("td")`. Actually the Navy color was overrided by previous line of JS code `select("table").selectAll("td").style("background-color", "lightblue")` and become lightblue color.

Comment: I tried to swaped two line of the JS codes, but the `style("background-color", "lightblue")` always has the highest priority than `.classed("bold-header", true)` in background-color.

Comment: @HelpMe Please see the update added by me in the above answer

Comment: I checked the rendered html and found that instead of overriding, I made the html tag have both attributes (class & background-color) which is the cause of the problem. The override should be an update of the value of same attribute(i.e. background-color). So the conclusion may be as you say `Select the tag wisely`.